# Clicking accept on cookies pop-up when it requires cursor on screen?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, popup

I am trying to click accept on a cookie popup and it was being very flaky. It is extremely flaky and only seems to execute when the cursor is in a select few places on the screen. My current code:

[image]

I have tried alert(both dismiss & accept) and all click options, but the success rate is only around 40%. I am trying to close it before testing the backToTop button.

Comment: post code in text based form not images.

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML.